# Is there a way to get a coordinate of a point?

Tags: algorithm

This is an algorithm question.
Let say we know the coordinate of x1y1 and x2y2, is there a way to get the coordinate of x3y3(left) and x4y4 (right) exactly 90 degrees - 1 meter from x1y1?

[image]

Comment: Swap x/y components of difference between P1 and P2, then divide by absolute value and add to P1 or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Get the difference between P1 and P2, swap the x/y components, divide them by the absolute value of the difference and add/subtract those from P1 respectively. Example in Python:

```py
>>> P = namedtuple("P", "x y")
>>> p1 = P(3, 4)
>>> p2 = P(5, 3)
>>> dx = p2.x - p1.x
>>> dy = p2.y - p1.y
>>> a = (dx**2 + dy**2)**.5
>>> P(p1.x + dy/a, p1.y - dx/a)
P(x=2.552786404500042, y=3.1055728090000843)
>>> P(p1.x - dy/a, p1.y + dx/a)
P(x=3.447213595499958, y=4.894427190999916)
```